# How to make the Tkinter GUI app with MariaDB, to workin on other PC without installing MariaDB?

Tags: python, mariadb

Good Day to All. Please can someone help with the python app and the MariaDB?

I am a seaman, and for making my fuel calculations easier, and to not spend a lot of time with the calculation of fuel using a hard copy of "bunker tables" - I decided to make a simple app where I stored all tables data in MariaDB, and interact with those data using a Python 3 script and Tkinter GUI. On my laptop, it works pretty well, but if I want to use it on my working PC it doesn`t work without MariaDB (of course).

the question: what can be the best solution for my python script work on any other pc? My OS is Linux. The working machine is Win10. But I can run Linux by using Live CD. The problem is that I can`t install the DB. If I will compile the app that can be installed on Windows by a .exe file, how to add to this .exe file my database. My app looks so:
[my script GUI looks like...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttDIQ.png)

I`m using next imports:

```
''' python
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory, askopenfilenames, askopenfiles
import platform
import math
import mariadb
import sys
import os
from tkinter.messagebox import showerror, showinfo, askokcancel
from pathlib import Path
import insert_in_db
import db_commands_calc
'''
```

If is needed more information a can provide it.
I am new to IT community and apologise fore some mistakes.

Comment: You'd probably be better off by using  `sqlite` which is meant to live inside your Python application. It is backed by a single file, is available by default in Python and uses SQL as you're already used to. It'll allow you to run your application without having to install a third party daemon.

Comment: OK , I'll try. Thanks a lot @MatsLindh . I really didn't knew about it.

Comment: MariaDB makes sense if you're going to have many clients working with the same db, but as internal storage for a single application `sqlite` is usually better suited.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @MatsLindh's comment* (appeared after I'd started typing...)

It seems likely your app is not doing much more than storing and retrieving relatively small tables.  It's very unlikely you are using MariaDB to its potential, so swapping in a little sqlite database, which you store as a file on the machine you are running the code on will be a *lot* easier than hauling a whole db package around.  Swapping in sqlite will be as simple as importing it instead of `mariadb` and calling exactly the same SQL queries.

If you want something else to be distracted by ;) you could also rewrite it as a web app and host it on one of the many app hosting platforms who will provide the db for you.  That way you could get at the gui from anywhere in the world.  This would be the solution to consider if you envisage yourself needing to access it from around the world without your PC, but of course it doesn't answer what you asked.

Lastly, to answer the other questions: it *is* perfectly possible to install MariaDB on windows and there is no need to compile anything: an [installer is available](https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/10.6.4/); and MariaDB is largely a drop-in replacement for mysql, and that can also be [installed on windows](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/).  These database packages run separately from your python code anyhow (Linux may have hidden this from you as I believe ubuntu enables and starts the `mariadb` service when it is installed) and your code just communicates with it (you set this up with your first calls to `mariadb` in the python code).  However you are almost certainly better off with a simple sqlite file.

Running a live cd every time you want to use your app is a non starter.  It would also mean needing two media: a live cd, and your app on some kind of storage device.

There is no need to *compile* your python code (if that's what you meant by app).  Just install [Python for windows](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/) on your work machine and run the script the same way you would on linux.  (Tools for compiling python code to standalone executables do exist of course, but are probably overkill.  And in my experience getting nontrivial code to run is not straightforward: I've had problems with compiled code actually accessing static resources on my machine and thus failing; with windows defender refusing to allow the binary to run; and with compiled executables not working on all platforms).  Judging from your imports you don't have anything not in the standard library except `mariadb`, so if you swap that out for `sqlite` everything should just run, even in the Windoze (almost)Operating system.

*bother, I'd written this before I saw the comment exchange.  Posting anyhow.